# When does $f(x;\alpha)=\cos(\alpha x)-\sin^2x-1$ has unique zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This is a contest math question that I don't remember the reference.

> When does $f(x;\alpha)=\cos(\alpha x)-\sin^2x-1$ has unique zero?

Obviously, $f(0;\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$. I've no idea what theorem can be used here. Any idea?

Comment: Not, I hope, an ongoing contest?

Comment: @GerryMyerson:No. I know the policy of math.SE and I've read this post: [math.SE policy on question from ongoing contests](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6206/9464) on meta. If there is any unnecessary "confusion", I would vote to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\cos(\alpha x) - 1 -\sin^2(x) = 0 \implies \cos(\alpha x) = 1 + \sin^2(x) \geq 1$$

Comment: Indulging in calculus for so long that I didn't notice how few facts I actually need to solve this "high school" problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Check this fact

$$ |\cos(x)| \leq 1 \,. $$